# What should happen when a WordPress Plugin is activated across the network (Network Wide Activation)

Tags: plugin-development, multisite, wp-admin

I'm used to WordPress, but something got my attention as described below:

For WordPress Network Wide Plugin Activation: wouldn't it be efficient to have an UI to allow super admins to control how the Plugin settings are being updated across the network.

For example, if the Plugin is activated network wide, then we should only run the plugin activation hook on the main blog, and retrieve the options accordingly for other blogs on the network by using the main blog. Meaning we only have to run the Plugin Activation Hook one blog, the main blog, even if there's 1000+ blogs on the network.

Next we can allow super admins to decide whether or not to show the **update for blog only** and **update across network** settings buton.

For the **update for blog only** settings button, if updating the plugin options on any blog for the first time, it will **run the plugin activation process and update settings for that blog only**.

For the **update options** settings button, it will just update the settings on the main blog.

So would this feature be great on plugins or not?